# Is there a method to implement a non-uniform deformation of a 3D mesh?

Tags: python, 3d, mesh, vtk, itk

I'm working with a 3D mesh in VTK. I want to apply on that a non-uniform deformation that means a Laplacian deformation, in which the global features of the mesh are preserved. 
To explain better the problem: I don't want to scale the mesh, at the end I would like to obtain an irregular shape of the body where the distances between points respect the constraints imposed by the reality of the structure.

Do you know a way to solve the problem in Python? 
I have read something about ITK but I had problems to use it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

ITK has a [LaplacianDeformationQuadEdgeMeshFilter](https://itk.org/Doxygen/html/classitk_1_1LaplacianDeformationQuadEdgeMeshFilter.html). You will need to convert `vtkPolyData` into an `itk::Mesh`. [This](https://github.com/InsightSoftwareConsortium/ITKApps/blob/master/Auxiliary/vtk/vtkPolyDataToITKMesh.cxx) is a possible starting point. If some of the required classes are not wrapped for Python, ask for that on the [ITK forum](https://discourse.itk.org/).